# Relation between the length of the list and the math formula

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
lst = [a,b,c,d,e...]
```

and math formula :

```
x = b/(b/a+b/c+b/d+b/e...+1)
```

I do not know in advance how many members(numbers) have list.
How to create a formula in relation to the length of the list?

Example:

```
lst = [12,23,45,65,78]
x = 23/(23/12+23/45+23/65+23/78+1)
```

Comment: Presumably you want *float* and not *integer* division here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a function

```
def equation(l):
    b = float(l[1])    # this avoids int division
    return b / sum([b/i for i in l])
```

Testing

```
>>> equation([1,2,3,4,5])
0.43795620437956206
>>> lst = [12,23,45,65,78]
>>> equation(lst)
5.642100849145612
```

Comment: i was thinking that, the +1 is actually `b/b`.

Answer (score 0):

sipmly you can use `in` operator ! and dont need to length of list !

```
x=[list[1]/sum(([(list[1]/i) for i in list])
```

anyway you can access to length of list by [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function !

Comment: This produces `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`, not the expected `5.642100849145612`.

Comment: Or, when using Python 3 or `from __future__ import division`, it produces `[0.923076923076923, 0.9583333333333334, 0.9782608695652173, 0.9848484848484849, 0.9873417721518987]`, which even when summed doesn't produce the expected outcome.

Comment: Your denominator is still wrong. It is `list[1]/i` not `list[1]/i+list[1]`

Comment: And you don't need to make a special case for the `1`, because that is just `b/b`

Comment: @Cyber yes,,, thanks for reminding at first i have been confused ! as you and other :)

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7, do this -

```
from __future__ import division
lst = [a,b,c,d...]
if len(lst < 2):
   raise(Execption)
else:
   num = lst[1]
   den = 0
   for i in range(lst[1] + lst[2:]):
      den += num/i
   den+=1
   print num/den
```

Answer (score 0):

A close inspection reveals, your formula can be simplified and generalized

`x = b/(b/a+b/c+b/d+b/e...+1)` to
`x = 1/(1/a+1/c+1/d+1/e...+1)`

So you can rewrite your sum as `1/sum(1./n for n in lst)`

Comment: In this very case the OP has given, the correct should be `23/sum([23/x for x in [12,23,45,65,78]])` (integer division).

Comment: @kroolik: that's a big assumption; we don't even know what major Python version is used here. And even then, Abhjit's simplification applies.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes the simplification applies when float division is in place.